# how can i capture network request waterfall of feature phone devices browser like chrome dev toolbar

Tags: browser, google-chrome-devtools, mobile-devices, nokia-s40

i want to test my site on feature phone like nokia asha phones , user agent does not give exact behavior . for smartphone i can connect my android device to chrome browser using USB debug mode and can inspect element , how to do this thing for feature phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The DevTools remote debugging uses a very specific protocol to talk to the remote device over. If that device doesn't expose the protocol, you can't see into it with DevTools directly.

Comment: hi garbee , any other way that i can do maximum testing of my site on feature phone ?